# change label font at run-time gives error

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, fonts

i want to change the font of all labels of a web page. I write the following code but it gives error that font is read only property. I need it very urgent to do . Can anyone help

Code is here

```
 Dim ctrl As Control
        Dim fnt As New Font("Verdana", 8, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point)

        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf ctrl Is Label) Then
                lbl = CType(ctrl, Label)
                lbl.Font = fnt
            End If
        Next
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You should use CSS to change the style of your labels.

Comment: sorry i need to do this urgent but in earlier work done by others dont use CSS, they do it by property of each label so applying css dont work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing Winforms and ASP.NET. You said that you want to change the font of labels on your WebPage, so i assume that it's an ASP.NET-Webaplication.

I strongly recommend to use [CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4kete56.aspx) instead. But if you need something working fast, you should replace your code with this:

```
 Public Sub ApplyFontStyleRecursively(ByVal parentControl As System.Web.UI.Control, ByVal fontInfo As FontInfo)
    If TypeOf parentControl Is Label Then
        DirectCast(parentControl, Label).Font.CopyFrom(fontInfo)
    End If

    For Each c As System.Web.UI.Control In parentControl.Controls
        ApplyFontStyleRecursively(c, fontInfo)
    Next
End Sub
```

and call it:

```
Dim lbl As New Label
lbl.Font.Name = "Verdana"
lbl.Font.Bold = True
ApplyFontStyleRecursively(Me.Page, lbl.Font)
```

Comment: In my test-application it does, even if the labels are in GridView-Rows. Then you should show us your aspx-code and the part where you've tried to call this function(edit your question). Have you used the above code or the one that i've posted first? The difference was that i've changed `MergeWith` to `CopyFrom`.

Comment: i create a blank page add five labels to it , after that i write the lines in second block of code at page-load and upper block as sub, when i view the page in browser, labels were showing the default font. so No change

Comment: THank you , it works my mistake SO Apolize to you .Very very thanks to help

Comment: It's working with static labels and labels in GridView(dynamic child-controls) from Page_Load and from Button_Click(PostBack) without any problems. Are you sure that you are using the code above and not the [first version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6532206/revisions)? 
Edit: Glad i could help, consider to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)

Comment: i already accepted , same i do for buttons .works perfectly with little change for button also